# How can i create a new matrix with the non NA values from another matrix and the row and column they were found in?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have an *n* x *n* matrix named *d* which is filled with mostly NA values but has some random values spread throughout.

I need to make a new matrix named *ds* with three columns named *head*, *tail* and *weight*, where *weight* is the value found in the matrix *d*, and *head* and *tail* are the row and column respectively of *d* where that particular value for *weight* was found.

Matrix *d*:

```
n = 1000 
d = runif(n*n) 
d[d < 0.80] = NA 
d = matrix(d,nrow=n,ncol=n) #reshape the vector 
diag(d) = NA # no self-loops 
d[upper.tri(d)] = t(d)[upper.tri(d)] # undirected graphs are symmetric

str(d)
num [1:1000, 1:1000] NA NA NA 0.861 NA ...
```

Desired output of `str(ds)` and `head(ds)`:

```
str(ds) 
num [1:99858, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2 
..$ : NULL 
..$ : chr [1:3] "head" "tail" "weight" 

head(ds) 
     head tail    weight 
[1,]    1   15 0.9205357 
[2,]    1   16 0.9938016 
[3,]    1   29 0.9480700
```

The actual values that return in the matrices above are not important because they will be randomly generated but my final output should look similar.

What I have tried:

```
head = c()
tail = c()
weight = c()
for (i in 1:n)
  for (j in 1:n)
    if (is.na(d[i][j]) == FALSE)
      head[i] = i
      tail[i] = j
      weight[i] = d[i][j]
ds = cbind(head, tail, weight)
```

However, this results in the following:

```
str(ds)
 num [1:1000, 1:3] NA NA 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "head" "tail" "weight"

head(ds)
     head tail weight
[1,]   NA   NA     NA
[2,]   NA   NA     NA
[3,]    3   NA     NA
[4,]   NA   NA     NA
[5,]   NA   NA     NA
[6,]   NA   NA     NA
```

Again, how can I search through matrix *d* for non-NA values, and when they are found update the matrix *ds* with the row it was found in, the column it was found in, and the value itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this cleanly with two nice R tricks for working with matrices: `which(arr.ind = TRUE)` and matrix indexing in `[`. Below I've only modified your setup code to add a seed for reproducibility and to make `n` 10 so you can see all the elements and convince yourself this is doing what it is supposed to.

First we use `which` to return a matrix of the non-NA row and column indexes in the matrix `d`. With `arr.ind = TRUE`, we keep one index per dimension of the input instead of flattening to a vector before indexing. Second, we column-bind the indices with with a vector of the corresponding weights obtained by passing that index matrix to `[`. You can visually compare `d` and `out` and see that the values line up.

```r
set.seed(1)
n = 10 
d = runif(n*n) 
d[d < 0.80] = NA 
d = matrix(d,nrow=n,ncol=n) #reshape the vector 
diag(d) = NA # no self-loops 
d[upper.tri(d)] = t(d)[upper.tri(d)]

indices <- which(!is.na(d), arr.ind = TRUE)
out <- cbind(indices, d[indices])
colnames(out) <- c("head", "tail", "weight")
head(out)
#>      head tail    weight
#> [1,]    4    1 0.9082078
#> [2,]    6    1 0.8983897
#> [3,]    7    1 0.9446753
#> [4,]    8    2 0.9919061
#> [5,]    9    3 0.8696908
#> [6,]    1    4 0.9082078
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>